# Forcibly Remove .php On Request

Tags: php, .htaccess

I know with .htaccess, you can request a file without the extension, like (page.php) can be requested as (page).

The following is the code in my .htaccess file to enable this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This code is only able to work when just (page) is requested. How do I make it so that by request, (page.php) is forcibly rewritten to just (page)? Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: https://github.com/phanan/htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(.+)\.php(?:\s|\?) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

Note: i wrote this code to make it work with `/some_page.php` but also with `/folder/subfolder/.../some_page.php`

Comment: While this does remove the .php. It changes www.example.com/page.php to www.example.com/home/username/public_html/page, which I do not really like.

Comment: I guess you're on a shared hosting, which could be misconfigured. I edited my code to fit with your case